# updateItem 'Expected' check for just one value in string set

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a conditional updateItem call using php SDK2, but having trouble figuring out how to check for only a single value within a string set.

For Exmple: I have a string set in dynamoDB:

{"a","b","c"}

I want to do an updatedItem call, and delete one of those values, but error out if the value doesn't exist. So, if I attempted to remove "d" from the above set, I want dynamoDB to throw an error, not just silently ignore the fact that "d" doesn't exist in my string set.

I've tried:

```
    'Expected' => array(
        myAttribute => array(
            'Exists' => true,
            'Value' => array(Type::STRING_SET => array("d"))
        )
     )
```

This fails, however, even if the value was, for example, "a". I think the reason is that dynamoDB thinks I want it to validate the entire set, not just one value in it.

Is there a way to do a conditional put and verify just a single value within the set?

I can do a getItem call, grab the string set as an array and do my own checking, but I'd love to do it all in one call if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [UpdateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) seems to indicate that DynamoDB looks at the value as a whole, and that you cannot have a condition based on a value within a set.

If you want a solid confirmation about whether or not you can do this or if you want to make a feature request for it, I would post on the [official DynamoDB forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131).

Comment: Yes, after doing some more testing and digging I arrived at the same conclusion. Thanks,